# How can I loop my code so it will go up in increments?

Tags: python-3.x

I want my code increase in increments each time it loops but I am unsure how to do it.How to I get it to repeat itself while increasing by $10, 10 times.

This is what I have so far:

```
def money():
amount = float(input("Enter NZ convertion amount:$ "))
AUD = amount*0.96
US = amount*0.75
Euro = amount*0.67
GBP = amount*0.496
print('NZ$', amount,'AUD: {}, US:{}, Euro: {}, GBP: {}'.format(AUD, US, Euro, GBP))
return
money()
```

any ideas?

Comment: please explain what you want to do, what loops how many times loop, what values you want to loop over?

Comment: I want the initial amount entered ($10) to increase by $10 on each new line, and repeat 10 times, while updating the conversion amounts. Sorry English isn't my first language. Have updated post as reference.

Comment: Spelling: `convertion => conversion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply wrap the calculation and printing part into a 10 times for loop like this?

```
def money():
    amount_ = float(input("Enter NZ conversion amount:$ "))
    for i in range(1, 11):
        amount = amount_ * i
        AUD = amount*0.96
        US = amount*0.75
        Euro = amount*0.67
        GBP = amount*0.496
        print('NZ$', amount,'AUD: {}, US:{}, Euro: {}, GBP: {}'.format(AUD, US, Euro, GBP))
    return
```

Comment: @C.Calzana Glad. Kindly consider marking the answer 'Accepted' if it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
AUD = 0.96
US = 0.75
EUR = 0.67
GBP = 0.496

def money(delta, times):
    amount = float(input("Enter NZ convertion amount:$ "))

    for dta in range(times):
        amt = amount + delta * dta 
        print('NZ$ {} AUD: {}, US:{}, Euro: {}, GBP: {}'.format(amt,
                                                                amt * AUD,
                                                                amt * US,
                                                                amt * EUR,
                                                                amt * GBP)

money(10.0, 10)
```